# Jittery zooming in a VewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having an issue that I hope someone can help me with.  I am displaying a multi-page document with scrolling and pinch-zooming.  Scrolling works fine, but when zooming, I am getting jittery behavior the farther down the document you go, say page 25 or so.

The document is represented by a ViewGroup (DocView) which holds an array of 100 custom views (DocPageView) representing pages.  DocView measures the pages and lays them out vertically in a single column.  A GestureDetector is used to monitor scrolling, and a ScaleGestureDetector for zooming.  In onScale(), I calculate a new scale factor, adjust the scroll positions, and call requestLayout().  In onLayout(), I calculate positions for the children and lay them out.  As an optimization, I add/remove children that won't be visible.

DocPageView is very minimal, it just draws itself with a page number.

When zooming, I am adjusting the scroll positions so as to keep the focus point of the pinch in approximately the same spot.  When getScrollY() is a small number, things work smoothly.  But when I scroll down to, say, page 25 and then zoom, there is a jitteryness that happens.

I think it's easier to see this in total, rather than post snippets here.  So here is the whole thing.

```
 [http://www.ross-perry.com/StackOverflow/ScalingTest.zip]
```

Please let me know if you have ideas, or have seen this sort of thing before.
Thank you.

Comment: looks like you are doing some work on all the pages 1-25 which is too much to be finished in 16ms (the time between frames).

Comment: Thanks Henry.  I tried limiting onScale to no more often than 25 ms, and it's still happening.  Also tried 50 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have bothered everyone.  Turns out that with every new scale value, I recalculate the new positions of the pages in onLayout.  Turns out I have an integer arithmetic error that accumulates as the page number increases.  I've eliminated that and now all is well.